# Disabling the firewall in Ubuntu on an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, firewall

How do I disable the Ubuntu server firewall running inside an amazon instance, though, without using ssh. I am not able to access via ssh because of the timeout error, I think it has a firewall on the server blocking but I can not disable it precisely because it can not access. I need to somehow disable it, directly from the Amazon web console. How do I do?

I already configured the security group in several ways, so I finally left it, with all the ports open for testing.

[image]

My route table is:

[image]

My ACLs is:

[image]

My instance settings:
[image]

Already tried to connect like this using openssh:

ssh -i "c: \ key \ owlcom.pem" ubuntu@ec2-54-149-193-61.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

and so

ssh -i "C: \ key \ owlcom.pem" X.X.X.X <- elastic ip

and so

ssh -i "C: \ key \ owlcom.pem" ubuntu@x.x.x.x

none of them works on any of my computers using openssh or putty., setting the putty correctly with the key.ppk

Comment: Add the following information to your question. 1) Post your security group. 2) Post your NACL. 3) Is your Ubuntu server in a private or public subnet? 4) Post your route table for the VPC. 5) Post your route table for the subnet. 6) Do you have a EIP address or Public IP address assigned to your EC2 instance.

Comment: You should not add 0.0.0.0/0 Ingress rule on port 22. It is a bad practice. Instead if you must, whitelist your IP address in Ingress.

Comment: I'll edit the question with the information

Comment: FYI: EC2 public DNS entries are built from the public IP. So smudging one and not the other is pointless.

Comment: Have you verified that you can use SSH to connect from your computer to any other computer? It's possible that there's an outbound firewall rule at your place of work that prevents this connection.

Comment: And lastly, I'd stick with the default network ACLs and use security groups to control access.

Comment: Real lastly: what are the outbound rules for your network ACL?

Comment: 100 - ALL Traffic - ALL - ALL - 0.0.0.0/0 - ALLOW

Comment: * -  ALL Traffic - ALL - ALL - 0.0.0.0/0 - DENY

Comment: I removed the input rule that I created with my ip (SSH) and kept only the default again. Same problem.

Comment: Please post the route table for subnet-4168e309

Comment: Solved! Uncomplicated Firewall

Comment: All the above solution didn't work for me, finally, I have disabled instance firewall setting by aws session manager.

Comment: @Anderson, How did you solve the issue? I think I have encountered a similar problem as you. Here is my case, I enabled the firewall by using ufw command when I logged in my EC2 instance; after I logged out, tried to SSH again, SSH didn't work, and showed timeout.
Thanks in advance if you can share your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: You will have to have access to the AWS dashboard in order to follow this procedure:

1. In your AWS Dashboard, please go to  Services > Compute > EC2 so you can see all your EC2 instances (make sure you are in the correct region).
2. Once in the EC2 dashboard, go to the "Instances" tab. Once there, locate the instance in which you want to disable the firewall. Click in it and you  should be able to see a summary of the instance in the lower part of the website. After that, go to the Security Group section and click on "view inbound rules". There you will be able to see all the open ports your instance has.
3. To modify such ports, you actually need to modify the Security Group rules your instance is attached to. To do so, click in the security group name in the panel where the "view inbound rules" was. It should take you to another page where you will be able to edit all the firewall rules.

I hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: I will accept your answer because it answers the question I asked, about the firewall, but unfortunately the problem continues, even modifying I can not access via ssh. Timeout error.

Comment: You need to explicitly allow to connect to port 22 via TCP. If you edit your security group and add an exception to allow anywhere (not recommended) or only your IP (the better approach) to connect via SSH, it will work

Comment: Yes, i do it, only anyway not works.

Comment: Could you please post the exact command you are using to connect to your instance? Please use x's for your instance's IP.

Comment: I'll edit the question with the information

Comment: question changed.

Comment: @Anderson what is the error outputted by putty or openssh... have you tried it using cygwin?

Comment: Network Error: Timed out i'm not trial cygwin. In the Mac prompt ocurrs the same errors.

Comment: Try this in your mac: Copy your `pem` file to the dir `~/.ssh`. Once you have your `owlcom.pem` file in that dir go ahead and execute the following: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/owlcom.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx`.  Does it still time-out? NOTE: You might have to run `sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh/owlcom.pem` after you copy the file or the terminal might complain about the file permissions

Comment: I don't know how this is the accepted answer! You cannot change firewall rules from the security group...There are four ways of getting access to your instance as outlined here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-resolve-ssh-connection-errors/

I chose Method 4 and regained access to my instance...

Comment: saved my long days :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't an Ubuntu firewall issue. It is likely that it is a security group configuration problem.

AWS by defaults limits the access to your instance quite heavily but to enable it you will need to add your ip address a security group used by your instance.

To do this (Assuming you are using IPv4):

To add a rule to a security group for inbound SSH traffic over IPv4 using the console

1. In the navigation pane of the Amazon EC2 console, choose Instances.
   Select your instance and look at the Description tab; Security
   groups lists the security groups that are associated with the
   instance. Choose view rules to display a list of the rules that are
   in effect for the instance.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Security Groups. Select one of the security groups associated with your instance.
3. In the details pane, on the Inbound tab, choose Edit. In the dialog, choose Add Rule, and then choose SSH from the Type list.
4. In the Source field, choose My IP to automatically populate the field with the public IPv4 address of your local computer. Alternatively, choose Custom and specify the public IPv4 address of your computer or network in CIDR notation. For example, if your IPv4 address is 203.0.113.25, specify 203.0.113.25/32 to list this single IPv4 address in CIDR notation. If your company allocates addresses from a range, specify the entire range, such as 203.0.113.0/24.
5. In the Source field, choose My IP to automatically populate the field with the public IPv4 address of your local computer. Alternatively, choose Custom and specify the public IPv4 address of your computer or network in CIDR notation. For example, if your IPv4 address is 203.0.113.25, specify 203.0.113.25/32 to list this single IPv4 address in CIDR notation. If your company allocates addresses from a range, specify the entire range, such as 203.0.113.0/24.
6. Choose Save.

SOURCE: [Amazon Web Services Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

Comment: If you're using IPv6 visit the source and there are instructions there.

Comment: Hello, I have already done all these procedures, but nothing worked, I have been trying for 3 days, I have already followed several tutorials, videos, amazom help, but even though everything seems to be correct, the same error continues.

Comment: Can you post the Security Groups and their settings that are attached to the instance?

Comment: yes. i'm editing the question now.

Comment: question changed.